# Emacs Dired not working - Searching for program: no such file or directory, ls

Tags: emacs, dired

When I open emacs, and type `C-x C-f RET`, the minibuffer says

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory, ls
```

This also happens when I press return after having typed any directory name.  Dired doesn't work when i use `C-x d` either.  Finding files works fine.

I'm using mac os x 10.11 and GNU Emacs 24.5.1.  Is there something that could have been put in `.emacs` to cause this? Also, it seemed to be working fine until I restarted my computer.

Comment: What does `getenv` return for `PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Racket v6.5/bin I'm using that plugin that makes emacs aware of you env variables.

Comment: I just ended up reinstalling emacs.  After about the 4th reinstall, it seemed to work.

Comment: Your problem was no doubt that the program `ls` was not in your `PATH`.

Comment: I could use ls in bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which ls` in bash to find where `ls` is located, say it is in `/bin/ls` whose parent directory is `/bin`. Then you need to add the parent directory `/bin` to both `PATH` and `exec-path` with following code.

```py
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/bin")))
```

Note that the parent directory `/bin` should be both in `PATH` and `exec-path`, to check if this config is setup:

- `M-x get-env PATH RET`
- `M-x describe-variable exec-path RET`

Sometime `/bin` may not appended to `exec-path` correctly, you can use Emacs's own customizations workflow

[image]